# How to stop setInterval when all Ajax calls are finished?

Tags: javascript, php, html

This is working fine, but I'm trying to find a good solution to stop Javascript `setInterval` when all responses has been fetched from a database through Ajax.

A for loop inside a for loop could work, I think?!

**HTML:**

```
<!-- code is simplefied, problem is not about syntax, but the way to do it. -->

SELECT id FROM database WHERE x=y

$rows = countrows(); //know how much different output there is

for(i=1; i <= rows; i++) // Show div everytime there's a response
{
$data-> fetch();

<div id="<?php echo "div" . $i;?>"> 
   <?php echo 'id' . $data['id']; ?> 
</div>
}
```

Let's say we have 3 responses from database, and we have 3 `div`s with 3 different `id`s.

**Javascript:**

```
setInterval(getResponse(), 1000); //execute function every second

getResponse()
{

  for(i=1; i <= $rows; i++)
  {
     //Here is the problem
     //Stop getResponse function execution when all responses has been taken
     if(response[i] && reponse[i] && ...)
     {
       //Stop function
     }

     //Select id . $data['id'] WHERE div . $i = i;
     // GET VARIABLE FROM DATABASE WHERE ID = 'id' . $data['id'];
     if(response)
     {
       //INSERT THIS VARIABLE IN THE RIGHT DIV.
       $response[i] = true;
     } 
  }
}
```

Comment: You can either `break;` or `return` in order to "stop a for loop in a function"

Comment: Use [`window.clearInterval(intervalId)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval)

Comment: The question is more how to know when all response[i] has been set to true so that I can stop it

Answer (score 2):

Save interval identifier to the accessible object or variable:

```
window.responseLoopInterval = window.setInterval(getResponse(), 1000);
```

then use [`window.clearInterval()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers.clearInterval) + `return` to prevent function execution

```
// somewhere in getResponse() function
if(... stop condition ...){
    window.clearInterval(window.responseLoopInterval); // remove interval loop
    return; // prevent further function execution
}
```

Comment: The problem is more about the if condition to stop the loop.
Ex. with 2 responses, response[1] && response[2] has been set to true.
then if condition will look like this: if(response[1] && response[2]).
But the number of responses is a variable, so I don't know how much response[i] I'll have...

Comment: @user1824508 `if(response.length >= 2){ ...stop loop... }` ?